# Changing the width of a td

Tags: html, css

I have constructed a table with a scrollable table body. Now I am having some difficulty adjusting the width of the table data cell. Changing the value of the width of the td has no effect on the size. Please see the code below.

This snippet contains the HTML and CSS:

```css
#d2 {
  border: solid black;
  width: 20%;
  height: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#d1 {
  border: solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8%;
  height: 28%;
}

tr {
  width: 100vw;
}

td {
  border: solid black;
  width: 100px;
  /* changing the value of the width here have no effect*/
  height: 7vh;
}

#tro1,
#tro2,
#tro3 {
  display: block;
  border: solid black;
  height: 7.4vh;
  width: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<div id='d1'>
  <table>
    <tr id='tro1'>
      <th> Centro</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='tro2'>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='tro3'>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </table>


</div>

<div id='d2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually does look like it is working.  Your `#d1` and `#d2` have set widths which is cutting off the edges of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the width of the `td` then you can also use `min-width` property of CSS.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
#d2 {
  border: solid black;
  width: 20%;
  height: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#d1 {
  border: solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8%;
  height: 28%;
}

tr {
  width: 100vw;
}

td {
  border: solid black;
  width: 100px;
  /* changing the value of the width here have no effect*/
  height: 7vh;
  min-width: 200px;
  /* changing the value of the width will work with min width bro*/
}

#tro1,
#tro2,
#tro3 {
  display: block;
  border: solid black;
  height: 7.4vh;
  width: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="td.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='d1'>
    <table>
      <tr id='tro1'>
        <th> Centro</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id='tro2'>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id='tro3'>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>

  <div id='d2'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**jsfiddle Output:** https://jsfiddle.net/defenderkhan/54ufsy1m/2/

You can also get it done easily by using [Bootstrap 4 classes](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: thank you. min-width attribute works perfect. i will also look into bootstrap 4 classes. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The widths are not changing because you have set the width of the parent `div` to fixed

```
width: 20%;
height: 28%;
```

try changing these values and then set the required width.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but how can i make the content of #d2 (the parent div) scroll when more table data is added. if i do not set the width of the parent div to a value, adding more table data moves the whole table to the next line which is not what i want.

Comment: try using min-width